# How to disable automatic login on Google Coral Dev Kit?

Tags: google-coral

How can I require a password to login on the Mendel OS? Specifically when using a display and keyboard+mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user` to disable the automatic login using HDMI